# Mongoose $group aggregation is not returning the desired results

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**Given this Member data:**

```
{ _id: 1, userType: 'CAPTAIN', firstName: 'Robert', lastName: 'Reichert', captain: 1}
{ _id: 2, userType: 'RIDER', firstName: 'Heather', lastName: 'Webre', captain: 1}
{ _id: 3, userType: 'CAPTAIN', firstName: 'Baba', lastName: 'Booey', captain: 3}
```

I'm trying to group the captains together and show the count of members associated with each captain (even if it's the captain itself). **The captain field references the _id in the same collection, so Baba Booey is his own captain and Robert is the captain for himself and Heather**.

**Desired results**

```
{ name: 'Baba Booey', count: 1 }, 
{ name: 'Robert Reichert', count: 2 }
```

**Here's the query:**

```
Member.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          captain: "$captain",
        },
        ridersCount: { $sum: 1 },
        firstName: { "$first": "$firstName" },
        lastName: { "$first": "$lastName" },
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: { lastName: 1, firstName: 1 }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        ridersCount: 1,
        firstName: 1,
        lastName: 1,
      }
    },
  ])
```

(*I've truncated some further filtering of the data because it's not essential to my question*)

I'm getting the results I want, **except it's showing the RIDER in the results instead of the CAPTAIN**, like this:

```
{ name: 'Baba Booey', count: 1 }, 
{ name: 'Heather Webre', count: 2 }
```

**When I switch it to use $last instead of $first it returns the correct results, but I think that is just because of the names in this example. I would like the name to ONLY show members who have userType: CAPTAIN**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing there can be only 1 captain per `captain` field, you can push the `$$ROOT` document in the first `$group` and [filtering](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the array according to the captain condition :

```
Member.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            captain: "$captain"
        },
        ridersCount: { $sum: 1 },
        "data": { $push : "$$ROOT" }
    },
}, {
    $project: {
        _id:0,
        ridersCount:1,
        data: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$data",
                as: "item",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$item.userType", "CAPTAIN"] }
            }
        }
    }
},{
    $unwind:"$data"
}])
```

It gives :

```
{ "ridersCount" : 1, "data" : { "_id" : 3, "userType" : "CAPTAIN", "firstName" : "Baba", "lastName" : "Booey", "captain" : 3 } }
{ "ridersCount" : 2, "data" : { "_id" : 1, "userType" : "CAPTAIN", "firstName" : "Robert", "lastName" : "Reichert", "captain" : 1 } }
```

Comment: Thanks Bertrand! That worked great. I'm completely new to $$ROOT, but found some good info here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/